# How to clear innerHTML option in select using onchange()?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select dropdown. When I choose an option in first select dropdown, then options in second select dropdown will show depends on the selected value from first dropdown.

Javascript:

```
function selectorView() {
    var namaServis = document.getElementById('namaServis').options;
    var jenisServis = document.getElementById('jenisServis').value;
    if (jenisServis == 'ringan') {
        var teks = ["Pemeriksaan lampu", "Pemeriksaan kelayakan ban", "Pemeriksaan roda", "Pemeriksaan rem", "Pemeriksaan oli", "Pemeriksaan busi", "Penyetelan Gas", "Pemeriksaan Rantai",
            "Pemeriksaan Oli Gear", "Pemeriksaan Kopling"];
        teks.forEach(function (el) {
            var divNamaServis = document.getElementById('namaServis');
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.innerText = el;
            divNamaServis.appendChild(option);
        });
        console.log(namaServis);
    }
    else if (jenisServis == 'berat') {
        var teks = ["Pemeriksaan kebocoran klep", "Membersihkan ruang bakar & piston", "Skur Klep"];
        teks.forEach(function (el) {
            var divNamaServis = document.getElementById('namaServis');
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.innerText = el;
            divNamaServis.appendChild(option);
        });
        console.log(jenisServis.length);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<label for="jenisServis">Jenis Servis</label><br>
            <select onchange="selectorView()" name="jenisServis" id="jenisServis">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose one..</option>
                <option value="berat">Berat</option>
                <option value="ringan">Ringan</option>
            </select><br>
            <label for="namaServis">Nama Servis</label><br>
            <select name="namaServis" id="namaServis">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose one..</option>
            </select>
```

This is the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/scn3Lb2o/5/

The problem is when I select an option on first dropdown, then I select another option the options in second dropdown will duplicate. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove all the options except the first from second select on each change of the first select. Also you should not reference the same element (`#namaServis`) multiple times inside the *if* and *else if* block:

```js
function selectorView() {
  var namaEl = document.getElementById('namaServis');
  while (namaEl.childNodes.length > 2) { // remove all option except the first
    namaEl.removeChild(namaEl.lastChild); 
  }
  
  var jenisServis = document.getElementById('jenisServis').value;

  if (jenisServis == 'ringan') {
    var teks = ["Pemeriksaan lampu", "Pemeriksaan kelayakan ban", "Pemeriksaan roda", "Pemeriksaan rem", "Pemeriksaan oli", "Pemeriksaan busi", "Penyetelan Gas", "Pemeriksaan Rantai",
        "Pemeriksaan Oli Gear", "Pemeriksaan Kopling"];
    teks.forEach(function (el) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.innerText = el;
      namaEl.appendChild(option);
    });
    //console.log(namaServis);
  }
  else if (jenisServis == 'berat') {
    var teks = ["Pemeriksaan kebocoran klep", "Membersihkan ruang bakar & piston", "Skur Klep"];
    teks.forEach(function (el) {
      var option = document.createElement('option');
      option.innerText = el;
      namaEl.appendChild(option);
    });
    //console.log(jenisServis.length);
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="jenisServis">Jenis Servis</label><br>
<select onchange="selectorView()" name="jenisServis" id="jenisServis">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose one..</option>
    <option value="berat">Berat</option>
    <option value="ringan">Ringan</option>
</select><br>
<label for="namaServis">Nama Servis</label><br>
<select name="namaServis" id="namaServis">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose one..</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Well, it works! Thanks. But I still confuse, I use your first code when you just use innerHTML to insert disabled options `var namaEl = document.getElementById('namaServis');
    namaEl.innerHTML = '<option value="" disabled selected>Choose one..</option>';
    var namaServis = namaEl.options;` this code works fine, but I still don't get it

Comment: @Jericho, while that also works but later I thought it would be better to use *while* loop to remove the options, thanks:)

Comment: if you using jQuery use $('#namaServis').find('option:not(:first-child)').remove();

Answer (score 2):

use this to clear options in the select before appending new content

```
document.getElementById('namaServis').options.length = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Define `options` variable outside the loop, `map` each option to `<option>${el}</option>` and add to `options` variable. Append `options` to the `namaServis` element.

```
function selectorView() {
    var namaServis = document.getElementById('namaServis');
    var jenisServis = document.getElementById('jenisServis').value;

    // Define options variable
    var options;

    if (jenisServis == 'ringan') {

        var teks = ["Pemeriksaan lampu", "Pemeriksaan kelayakan ban", "Pemeriksaan roda", "Pemeriksaan rem", "Pemeriksaan oli", "Pemeriksaan busi", "Penyetelan Gas", "Pemeriksaan Rantai", "Pemeriksaan Oli Gear", "Pemeriksaan Kopling"];

        // map through the options
        teks.map(function (el) {

            // Concatenate each option to options variable
            options += `<option>${el}</option>`;
        });

        // Set the innerHTML
        namaServis.innerHTML = options;

    } else if (jenisServis == 'berat') {
        var teks = ["Pemeriksaan kebocoran klep", "Membersihkan ruang bakar & piston", "Skur Klep"];

         // map through the options
        teks.map(function (el) {

            // Concatenate each option to options variable
            options += `<option>${el}</option>`;
        });

        // Set the innerHTML
        namaServis.innerHTML = options;
    }
}
```